# Whitespace counting program gives incorrect output

Tags: c

Below is a small program that I have written to count the number of times a space, newline or tab is entered from the keyboard.

However, I don't know what's going wrong. I am getting my counts as zero always no matter how many spaces or newlines are inputted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*program to count blanks ,tabs and newlines */

int main()
{
       int cnt_space=0,cnt_newline=0,cnt_tab=0;
       int c;

       while(c=getchar()!=EOF)
       {
         if(c==' ')
         {
           ++cnt_space;
         }
         if(c=='\n')
         {
           ++cnt_newline;
         }
         if(c=='\t')
         {
           ++cnt_tab;
         }
       }

       printf("spaces=%d\nnewlines=%d",cnt_space,cnt_newline);
       return 0;
 }
```

Comment: this: `#include < stdio.h>` usage looks odd..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this

```
while(c=getchar()!=EOF)
```

to

```
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
```

The reason why this matters is that getchar return value gets compared to EOF first, result being 0 or 1. Then the result value gets stored in c. So it would never match any of the conditions.

The reason why getchar gets compared to EOF first is because the != operator has a higher precedence than the = operator.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a pair of parentheses in the loop header:

```
while ( (c=getchar()) != EOF ) {
    ....
}
```

Currently, your assignment takes `getchar()!=EOF`, which is either `1` or `0`, and assigns it to `c`. This never matches the space`' '` or `'\n'`.

To learn more about *operation precedence* in C, take a look at [this chart](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html). Generally, though, it never hurts to add a pair of parentheses to force the operation order that you need. If you are having doubts about precedence of operations in the expression that you are writing, chances are that your readers would have doubts too.

Comment: @robert:its a constant whose value is -1

Comment: @RobertHarvey `EOF` is a negative integer constant, most often `-1`. It's the result `getchar()` returns when encountering the end of the input stream. With the parentheses, the result of getchar()` is assigned to `c` and then compared to `EOF`. Without the parentheses, the result of `getchar()` is compared to `EOF` and the result of that comparison is assigned to `c`.

Comment: I aid my readers with the placement of spaces, e.g., `while( (c = getchar()) != EOF ){`

Comment: It's sweet of you to give me that rep boost. :-) But from the badge description, I think I should save my edits for something more substantial, and I wouldn't want to risk getting into a style battle.

Comment: @JimBalter I think you're right about inserting spaces for clarity. I remember debugging my friend's code that was missing a pair of parentheses when we were testing control software for a conveyor. We spent a couple of hours debugging it, while a dozen of bag throwers were sitting around, collecting ten bucks an hour each. Part of the reason why finding the bug took us so long was that the expression was hard to read, so the error did not jump at us immediately.